# Laravel api blocks all requests with CORS

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I have a problem with all my requests sent in javascript on the api. They are all blocked by the CORS. When they are sent from postman, they work fine.

The fruitcake/laravel-cors library is already installed but has not fixed the problem.

Do you have any solutions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this fruitcake/laravel-cors package .Now Laravel 9 by default provides cors solution.

> Visit site from http://localhost:8000 not http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Working ? or not

Answer (score 0):

I am on laravel 8, and access to the api does not work in production.
Everything was working normally and since reinstalling the vps (on apache) it doesn't work anymore.
I don't know if it's apache or laravel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).